# Security risk of exposing php folder to browser

Tags: php

Is there any security risk in putting php files under the web folder on a web server, like this?

```
example.com/web/
example.com/web/php/
```

Someone once told me below is the preferred method, but is there any actual gain to this, security wise or otherwise?

```
example.com/web/
example.com/php/
```

The downside to this, is that you need to put an almost-empty php file under "web" that just includes the actual code. It would have been nice to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the security of your system shouldn't rely on keeping those php server scripts secret, but I still wouldn't openly share them without having a reason. You are better off keeping them outside of `/web` (assuming everything in `/web` is accessible externally)